# Why SetEditRow in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Is there any specific reason to use [SetEditRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.seteditrow.aspx) method in GridView instead of setting the edit index with [EditIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.editindex.aspx) property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the `SetEditRow` method for putting a row into edit mode. `EditIndex` is useful to get which index is currently in edit mode. It is also useful in other situations described in the remarks page.